# gufw firewall doesn't work in fedora

Tags: security, firewall, fedora

Yesterday I installed gufw successfully but it doesn't work I mean the software desn't have any response to clicking on it logo.

How can I solve it?

My computer os is fedora.

Comment: Did you disable firewalld, You can't have both at once.

Comment: @rtyocum  I did `#systemctl disable firewalld ` but I already have the said problem.